# How do I get rid of layout shift on page render?

Tags: reactjs

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setNavHeight(navRef.current!.clientHeight);
  }, []);    
<main style={{ height: `calc(100vh - ${navHeight}px)` }}></main>
```

As navHeight is null by default and it's calculated after component is mounted, there is a layout shift. Can I get rid of it?

Comment: This may not be the answer you want, but you can only assign an initial value to navHeight. This value is exactly the same as navRef.current!.clientHeight.

Comment: Please provide more code. It's crucial here where is the navigation placed. Inside `main` or somewhere else.

Comment: @Jannchie but aren't pixels dependent on device pixel ratio?  It would cause layout shift anyway, just not on my screen

Comment: Generally you need to test the height on various mainstream resolutions, and set different heights for different screens through js or css.

Comment: @kinduser the navigation is placed inside the same container as the main section. The container only has display: block and nothing else

Comment: More code would be helpful.